# Extra column in pgfgantt chart

Tags: pgfgantt

I have created a basic gantt chart using pdfgantt (pretty much copied one of the examples) but would like to make a couple of (extra) modifications to it.

I really need to be able to number my groups and bars and would like to have an extra column to the left hand side of the labels with this numbering (i.e. in the following example Part 1 would be numbered 1, task 1 of part 1 would be numbered 1.1 etc.).

I have my example below to which I would like to add this feature.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

```
\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{center}
 \begin{ganttchart}[
  x unit=2.0cm, y unit title=0.4cm, y unit chart=0.6cm, vgrid,
  title/.append style={draw=none, fill=RoyalBlue!50!black}, title left shift=0.01, title right shift=-0.01,
  title label font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},
  title label node/.append style={below=-1.6ex},title height=1,
  bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=OliveGreen!75},
  bar height=.3, bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!90}, bar label text={#1\hspace*{0.1cm}},
  group right shift=0.05, group top shift=.6, group height=.1, group peaks height=.2, group peaks width=0.1, group left shift=-0.05,
  group label node/.append style={align=right}, group label text={#1\hspace{0.2cm}},
  milestone left shift=0.94, milestone right shift=0.06, milestone height=0.4, milestone label text={#1\hspace*{0.1cm}},
  bar incomplete/.append style={fill=Maroon}]{1}{8}
  % Titles
  \gantttitle{2013}{3}\gantttitle{2014}{5} \\
  \gantttitle{Q4}{3}\gantttitle{Q1}{3}\gantttitle{Q2}{2}\\
  \gantttitle{10}{1}\gantttitle{11}{1}\gantttitle{12}{1}\gantttitle{1}{1}\gantttitle{2}{1}\gantttitle{3}{1}\gantttitle{4}{1}\gantttitle{5}{1} \\
  \ganttset{progress label text={}, link/.style={black, -to}}
  % Part 1
  \ganttgroup{Part 1}{1}{4} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=25, name=T1A]{Task 1}{1}{3} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=25, name=T2A]{Task 2}{2}{2} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=25, name=T3A]{Task 3}{3}{3} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=25, name=T4A]{Task 4}{3}{3} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=25, name=T5A]{Task 5}{3}{3} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=25, name=T6A]{Task 6}{3}{4} \\
  % Part 2
  \ganttgroup{Part 2}{4}{8} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=25, name=T1B]{Task 1}{4}{6} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=25, name=T2B]{Task 2}{4}{8} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=25, name=T3B]{Task 3}{6}{8} \\
  % Overviews
  \ganttgroup{Overview}{1}{8} \\
  \ganttmilestone{Milestone 0}{0} \\
  \ganttmilestone{Milestone 1}{2} \\
  \ganttmilestone{Milestone 2}{3} \\
  \ganttmilestone{Milestone 3}{8} \\
  \ganttset{link/.style={OliveGreen}}
 \end{ganttchart}
 \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: Please provide with the `\documentclass{}` and the used packages to your [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).